# Invariant subspaces under permutations

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups, invariant-subspace

I would like to show that the only proper and non-trivial vector subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$ that are invariant under all permutations of the coordinates are $\{(x,x,\ldots,x) \in \mathbb{C}^n:x\in \mathbb{C}\}$ and $\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n:\sum_i x_i = 0\}$.

Can you please provide a hint to start rather than a full solution? I would like to avoid using results from representation theory if possible.

Comment: If $C_n = (1 ~ 2 ~ \cdots ~ n)$ is the $n$-cycle, then $x \mapsto \frac{1}{n} (x + C_n x + C_n^2 x + \cdots + C_n^{n-1} x)$ is a projection onto $\langle (1, 1, \ldots, 1) \rangle$ with kernel $\{ x : x_1 + \cdots + x_n = 0 \}$...

Comment: Also, if $M$ is invariant under all permutations, it is invariant under all transpositions (which is actually equivalent). As transpositions are symmetric, also $M^\perp$ is permutation-invariant.

Comment: I'd imagine any proof is going to involve a lemma that $\{ x : \sum_i x_i = 0 \}$ is irreducible, i.e. any nontrivial subspace invariant under $S_n$ is all of this subspace.  To prove this fact, for example, if you do the same thing with $C_{n-1} = (1 ~ 2 ~ \cdots ~ n-1)$ on a member of this subspace, then you get a scalar multiple of $(1, 1, \ldots, 1, -(n-1))$.  Now see what you can do to prepare things so that the scalar multiple is nonzero; and then see why the subspace generated by permutations of $(1, 1, \ldots, 1, -(n-1))$ is all of this subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way (very vaguely, so you can do the main part by yourself):

It should be clear that you are almost done, if you can show the following: If the vector $v = (1,-1,0,\ldots,0)\notin M$, then $M=\operatorname{span}\{(1,\ldots,1)\}$. And this you can show as follows: If $v\notin M$, then the transposition $T_{12}$, restricted to $M$, is the identity on $M$ (you can prove this by looking at eigenvalues and eigenvectors). Thus, the first entries of vectors in $M$ must be equal. Now, transpose a little further and you'll see that indeed $M=\operatorname{span}\{(1,\ldots,1)\}$.